# Does interface instance creation will also create type object pointer for it?

Tags: c#, oop

Does using interface instead of abstract class when there is not need for concrete implementation would result in not creating a seperate type object for the base class (as interface going to be used instead)?

Example 1:

In the above example, the type object pointer is supposed to be created for both the classes.

```
    public abstract class Employee
    {
        public abstract string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public abstract double CalculateSalary();
    }
    public class Manager : Employee
    {
        public override string EmployeeName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override double CalculateSalary()
        {
            return 10000;
        }
    }
```

Example 2:
In the above example, as the method obj.GetType() just pointing to the actual Manager class, there will not be any type object created for the interface instance right?

```
    public interface IEmployee
    {
        string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        double CalculateSalary();
    }
    public class Manager : IEmployee
    {
        public string EmployeeName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double CalculateSalary()
        {
            return 10000;
        }
    }
```

I got bit confused with the IL generated for the interface :(

```
.**class** interface abstract auto ansi nested public IEmployee
{
} // end of **class** IEmployee
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear to me. Are you asking if it will create a `Type` that you can use to get information about the `IEmployee` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the only [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type) object that will be created, will be created for the `Manager` class. This will describe the members of `Manager`, regardless of whether they're implemented in the class itself, inherited from a base class or constitute an interface implementation.

From that `Type` object you can get a `Type` object for the base clas (through the `BaseType` property), or the `Type` object for the interfaces it implements (through the `GetInterfaces` or `FindInterfaces` methods), and enumerating the list of members can be filtered to include or exclude inherited members (through the `BindingFlags` parameter to `GetMembers`), but it's still a `Type` object that represents the `Manager` class.

Comment: In case#1, will the type object not created for Employee separately? I  mean, if the class is an fully abstract one, only the derived will have the type object created and if the abstract class contains at least one concrete stuff, type object will be created for that too? Please confirm my understanding.

Comment: A `Type` object is a construct used in Reflection to describe a type. It works the same way for concrete classes, abstract classes and interfaces, since it just *describes* the type, it doesn't instantiate them. You can have a `Type` object for an abstract class with no inheritors at all.

Comment: thank you @Avner. Any idea about why the IL generated with ".class" prefix?

Comment: I'm not much of an expert on MSIL, but from what I gather the `.class` directive is used to mark all user defined types in IL, whether they're mapped to C#'s `class`, `struct` or `interface`. The difference between a class and an interface in IL is basically an attribute.